# Reconnecting the Connection on Disconnect Event due to Network Failure - Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io to implement a real-time application. The client(Mobile phone web pages) connection get disconnects some time due to heartbeat test failure. That happened due to network issues. Is there a way to reconnect the connection on disconnect event from client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tune socket.io options to enable reconnection.

- `reconnection` - should be `true`
- `reconnectionDelay` (ms) - how long to wait before attempting a new
  reconnection
- `reconnectionDelayMax` (ms) - maximum amount of time to wait between
  reconnections. Each attempt increases the reconnection by
  the amount specified by `reconnectionDelay`.

Comment: I am not talking about the connection time failure. After successful connection, socket can disconnected. I need a way to handle that.

Comment: @andunslg I think that these options are about reconnection after socket was disconnected as well.

Comment: Found these issue. We need to implement all the call back to catch the re-connection.